# Bluemix docker scalable group for non HTTP requests

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

Can scalable group option on Bluemix container infrastructure work with protocols other than HTTP?
I created a simple TCP server, deployed in a single container on Bluemix and works fine. If I try to deploy it as a scalable group I can only assign HTTP port and it does not respond any more.
Is this a current limitation?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Cloud Foundry app you can only get port 80,433.  However if you run a container you can bind to any port you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but probably I have to clarify better: my question is more related to protocols than to ports. As for a single container all is working as I expected and needed for my particular use case: I opened up a custom port (9080) and used a custom protocol (no HTTP), the doubt I have is whether container scalable group can accept any protocol or it just accept HTTP and filters out any other protocol, as it seems from my tests.

Comment: Not properly true, actually only a limited set of ports are supported on containers, other ports need to be asked for opening through Bluemix support

Answer (score 0):

containers environment on Bluemix actually supports a limited list of TCP (not UDP) ports, and 9080 is contained in this list, so your server should work.

If you need any different port from the ones contained in this list you could always ask for the port being opened for your instance, through Bluemix support.